# Template class constructor overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, overload-resolution, constructor-overloading

I have a simple issue with ctor overload resolution for a class template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
enum EnumTypeVal { READ, WRITE };

template <class T>
class TemplateClassTest {
public:
    TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, T typeVal, EnumTypeVal e = READ,
                      const string & defaultStringVal = "default");
    TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, const char * charVal);
    TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, EnumTypeVal e = READ,
                      const string & defaultStringVal = "default");
private:
T type;
};

template <class T>
TemplateClassTest<T>::TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, T typeVal,
                                        EnumTypeVal e,
                                        const string & defaultStringVal)
{
    type = typeVal;
    cout << "In TemplateClassTest(const string &, T, EnumTypeVal, "
            "const string &)" << endl;
}

template <class T>
TemplateClassTest<T>::TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal,
                                        const char * charVal)
{
    cout << "In TemplateClassTest(const string &, const char *)" << endl;
}

template <class T>
TemplateClassTest<T>::TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, EnumTypeVal e,
                                        const string & defaultStringVal)
{
    cout << "In TemplateClassTest(const string &, EnumTypeVal, const string &)"
         << endl;
}

typedef TemplateClassTest<long long unsigned int> u32Type;
typedef TemplateClassTest<bool> boolType;

int main()
{
    u32Type l("test", "0"); //matches ctor 2
    u32Type v("test", 0); // ambiguity between ctor 1 and 2
    boolType b("test", "true"); //matches ctor 2
    return 0;
}
```

The second call fails to compile by throwing error:

> Call of overloaded 'TemplateClassTest(const char [5], int) is ambiguous.

Why does `int` matches to `const char *`? This situation can be solved by changing the `const char *` to `const string &` in ctor 2. But doing so, `boolType b("test", "true")` now gets matched to ctor 1 instead of ctor 2.

My requirements are:

- `u32Type v("test", 0)` should match ctor 1
- `boolType b("test", "true")` should match ctor 2.

Limitations are:

- ctor 1 and 3 signatures can't be changed
- user code calls in main() can't be changed.

Any help is highly appreciated..Thanks!

Comment: just leave the template constructor and specialize it for T=char const*

Comment: `typedef TemplateClassTest<int> u32Type;` would solve the problem, as ctor 1 becomes an Exact Match. I'm not sure if that wouldn't break something different, as `int` is not required to have exactly 32 bits.

Comment: This is the perfect example of why C++11 added the `nullptr` keyword.

Comment: @DyP: Suppose I have already another typedef TemplateClassTest<int> intType;

Comment: @CodeWarrior See the SFINAE solution in my answer. The `boolType b("test", "true")` getting matched to ctor 1 is definitely ugly.

Comment: @bobah: I guess the specialization for bool will serve my purpose since I want the ctor 2 for bool only. Why I am getting the following error: template<> class TemplateClassTest<bool> { TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, const char * charVal); };         template<>TemplateClassTest<bool>::TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, const char * charVal) { cout << "In TemplateClassTest(const string &, const char *)" << endl; } Why this is giving a template-id error?

Comment: @CodeWarrior 1) the ctor is private. 2) An out-of-line definition of a member function of an explicitly specialized class template does not contain a `template<>` for the explicitly specialized class template. Just use `TemplateClassTest<bool>::TemplateClassTest(const string&, const char*) { /*..*/ }`

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous because `0` is a null pointer constant. A null pointer constant can be implicitly converted to any pointer type -> a *null pointer conversion*. Therefore, ctor 2 is viable: `TemplateClassTest(const string&, const char*)`.

As an integer literal, `0` is of type `int`. Constructor 1, `TemplateClassTest(const string&, T, EnumTypeVal = READ, const string & = "default")`, therefore requires a conversion from `int` to `unsigned long long` -> an *integral conversion*.

Those two conversions, *null pointer conversion* and *integral conversion*, have the same rank (Conversion), hence the ambiguity.

---

[conv.ptr]/1

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a *null pointer conversion*.

---

A possible, but ugly fix that matches your constraints is to change the second constructor to:

```
template<class U,
         class V = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, const char*>{}>::type>
TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, U charVal);
```

That is, a greedy constructor template, restricted by SFINAE to only accept `const char*` as the second argument. This heavily restricts the implicit conversions applied to the second argument when trying to match this ctor.

The out-of-line definition becomes:

```
template <class T>
template<class U, class V>
TemplateClassTest<T>::TemplateClassTest(const string & stringVal, U charVal)
{
    cout << "In TemplateClassTest(const string &, const char *)" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..Why isn't it matching ctor 1 since it should have a better rank..since 0 is also type T in this case...How should I make u32Type v("test", 0) and boolType b("test", "true") to matche separate ctor's?

Comment: @CodeWarrior `0` as an integer literal is of type `int`, not of type `unsigned long long int`.